# vault.hashicorp.com/template-static-secret-render-interval is not working

Tags: hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I'm using the following hashicope annotations and these annotations are patched in the application pod using kubectl patch sts app-sts --patch "$(cat template.json)" command.

```
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: "update"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-extra-secret: 'vault-injector-secret'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-type: 'approle'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: 'auth/approle'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-role-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/.role-id'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-secret-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/.secret-id'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-vault-secrets.json: "/"
        vault.hashicorp.com/secret-volume-path-vault-secrets.json : "/etc/app-secrets"
        vault.hashicorp.com/template-static-secret-render-interval: "1m"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-vault-secrets.json: |
        {}
```

Even if I specify vault.hashicorp.com/template-static-secret-render-interval: "1m", the secret file get refreshed after each 5min. But I want to make it refresh after each 1min.

For simplicity, I kept console template empty here.

Can Anybody help me with this?